# Exclusão Física vs Exclusão Lógica

Tags: sql

Qual a vantagem de fazer exclusão lógica *(Ex: Setar uma flag indicando que o registro está ativo ou não)*, ao invés de realizar exclusão física?

É uma prática comum? É segura?

> Derivada de: [Physical vs. logical / soft delete of database record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378331/physical-vs-logical-soft-delete-of-database-record)

Comment: Realizar exclusão física na maioria dos casos não é recomendo, porque você não poderá reativar o tal registro. O que é uma funcionalidade a menos em sua aplicação/sistema, sendo que não há motivos para deleta-lo fisicamente.

Comment: @Gabe, curiosidade: como você achou a fonte original?

Comment: @bfavaretto Me indicaram. Nada supera o poder das massas :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Geralmente, use a **exclusão física** somente quando você sabe com certeza que não irá precisar mais do registro na tabela.

Use a **exclusão lógica** quando pode ser possível que você:

- possa **precisar restaurar** o registro em algum momento (undelete)
- obter informações dos registros deletados (várias vezes requisições do cliente e não do usuário).

A decisão sobre usar uma ou outra depende individualmente de cada caso. Mas na maioria dos casos o mais **recomendado é usar a exclusão lógica** quando há a mínima probabilidade de haver restauração dos registros deletados.
Uma query `WHERE tabela.Excluido = 0` não costuma denegrir performance, recaindo a preocupação mais sobre o tamanho de dados a armazenar. E claro, sobre a possibilidade de restaurar.

---

Uma alternativa também usada, em tabelas que possam vir a ter um tamanho gigante com um proporção alta de excluídos, é que mover os registros  para outra tabela exclusiva para Excluidos para não afetar a performance da tabela principal.

Porém nesse caso, deve-se tomar o cuidado porque pode ser possível que não possam ser restaurados *facilmente* caso tenham um **PK** com autoincremento.
Normalmente são usados para consultas de "históricos".

Esse caso pode ser usado também em questões legais, como guardar dados sobre os logins efetuados pelos usuários num site durante X anos em contraste com o dados somente informativos ao usuário/cliente do seu último login num site.

Answer (score 10):

Vantagens de usar uma deleção lógica:

- Auditorias: se você usar um campo data-hora para guardar a deleção, ao invés de um simples booleano / string, você pode saber quando foi deletado. E você pode usar índices e pesquisas sem problemas com isto, pois sua pesquisa será do tipo `WHERE dtExclusao = NULL` ou algo assim.
- Deleção mais fácil: não precisa se preocupar em manter algumas integridades na hora de fazer a deleção, já que não é feita uma deleção em cascata.
- possibilidade de no futuro implementar alguma solução de inteligência/BI, já que haverá um histórico de todos os dados que poderão ser utilizados

Desvantagens:

- você vai ter que controlar a deleção no seu código, sempre lembrando de ter um `WHERE` para poder deixar os deletados de fora
- se a tabela for muito grande e fragmentada (com alguns dados não-deletados bem espaçados no meio de vários dados deletados), a performance poderá cair, pois as tabelas são guardadas em "páginas" no disco, com algumas sendo carregadas na memória. Se os dados não-deletados estiverem todos em poucas "páginas", ótimo. Mas se o seu índice disser que tem um dado válido em cada página, o seu banco vai perder um tempo enorme lendo cada página para memória, extraindo só a linha que você precisa, e carregando a próxima página. Neste caso, para contornar isto, valeria a pena ter uma tabela de dados ativos e jogar os que forem apagados para outra tabela.
- os dados da deleção em cascata continuam todos nas mesmas tabelas, ou seja, um registro é marcado como apagado na tabela pai, mas nas tabelas filhas nada indica se o dado ainda está sendo usado ou não, e as tabelas podem ficar grandes, sem conseguir jogar dados para uma tabela especial dos que foram apagados
- tempo / custo de backup: já que os backups completos (full) terão um monte de dados que na verdade foram deletados
- demora para gravar dados: se os índices são grandes (já que as tabelas podem ser grandes, armazenando todos os registros excluídos), a cada gravação de um novo dado pode exigir um grande tempo de construção do índice, e assim cada ação de gravar pode ter uma performance baixa

Answer (score 8):

Bom, a vantagem ou desvantagem dos dois tipos de exclusão depende muito das necessidades do seu sistema.

Antes de decidir qual é a melhor prática para o seu caso, recomendo dar atenção aos seguintes aspectos:

- Setar uma *flag* para indicar se o registro está ativo ou não implica ter que realizar checagens (claúsulas `WHERE`) em cada *query* desse ponto em diante;
- Desempenho pode ser sim um grande problema ocasionado por optar pela exclusão lógica, portanto é preciso levar em conta a complexidade de seu banco de dados e as relações entre as entidades a fim de verificar se isso realmente seria um empecilho ou não;
- É imprescindível realizar uma análise da frequência com que determinado dado previamente excluído é requisitado/buscado. Através disso, você saberá se o melhor a se fazer é utilizar um campo bit, criar uma tabela adicional que guardará determinada informação ou simplesmente adicionar campos que contenham data de modificação, alteração e/ou exclusão para um controle mais amplo.

**Se é necessário** manter registros inativos, vá em frente e use `backups` para guardar seus dados, implemente *triggers* que os desviem e poupe recursos conforme o necessário.
Em suma, dar permissões aos usuários que realmente devam ter o poder de exclusão, descartar aquilo que impede a otimização de seu sistema e promover uma boa interatividade máquina-usuário é sempre a melhor alternativa.

Answer (score 6):

Existem dois propósitos principais:

O primeiro é que você não perde a informação definitivamente, ela permanece em algum lugar para fins de auditoria por exemplo (existem soluções melhores para isso, como manter registros especiais de histórico).

Segundo, é manter os relacionamentos. Por exemplo, vamos ver o caso típico que é desativar usuários de um sistema:
Enquanto estava ativo, esse usuário realizou operações, cadastros, etc. Cada uma dessas entidades fica ligada ao usuário responsável através de campos do tipo "id_usuario", "created_by", etc, tudo apontando para aquela linha da tabela de usuários. Se eliminasse esse usuário usando um DELETE, todos esses registros ficariam quebrados, apontando para um usuário que não existe. Nessa hora é conveniente apenas inativar o usuário, assim ele não consegue mais entrar no sistema, e ao mesmo tempo você pode consultar os registros deixados por ele que estarão apontando para o usuário correto.

Se é uma prática comum:

Em algumas organizações isso é obrigatório, é simplesmente proibido dar DELETE em registros na base. Mesmo quando não precisaria. Por isso o ideal é mesmo avaliar cada situação e ver qual a melhor solução. Em muitos casos a exclusão lógica realmente é útil, e em outros você terá que usá-la mesmo não sendo :-)

Comment: bem lembrado da integridade referencial

Answer (score 3):

Evite a exclusão lógica para não ficar com dados inúteis e irrelevantes no seu banco de dados.

Utilize a exclusão lógica somente quando for necessário! É sim uma prática comum e segura, na medida em que o código da aplicação cuide corretamente do caso (o framework Laravel, por exemplo, cuida das exclusões lógicas com extrema facilidade para o desenvolvedor).

A pergunta que resta é: **quando** seria necessário usar exclusão lógica?

Através da exclusão lógica, você pode recuperar o dado "deletado", ou seja, você preserva histórico, e mantém integridade no banco de dados.

Um exemplo: um **produto** numa loja virtual. Na medida em que existam pedidos feitos contendo esse produto, será conveniente fazer uma exclusão lógica do produto. Assim, é possível identificar os itens em pedidos pretéritos, mesmo que o produto possa ser "excluído". Ou seja: com a exclusão lógica do produto, você preserva os dados desses pedidos.

Há muitos outros casos onde a exclusão lógica é útil, importante e valiosa. Mas se não for útil nem necessária, o melhor é fazer a exclusão física mesmo, para não deixar a base de dados poluída.