# Como fazer um histórico

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

Olá, estou com uma dúvida e não sei como começar a resolver ela.
Estou utilizando o asp.net mvc e tenho que criar uma tabela de históricos, onde ele faz uma cópia de uma determinada parte, mesmo se eu deletar a original, a cópia fica.

essa é a model que preciso copiar, mas o nome da função ou um link de como fazer já está de bom proveito para mim.

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NameItem { get; set; }
    public string Attachments { get; set; }
    public int FicheId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntidadeEstrangeira")]
    public Ficha Fiche { get; set; }
    public string NameUser { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntidadeEstrangeira")]
    public Location Location { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10304/exclus%c3%a3o-f%c3%adsica-vs-exclus%c3%a3o-l%c3%b3gica

Comment: Mais não entendi, em qual momento é a sua duvida?

Comment: Bfavetto me salvou, obrigada e desculpa pela pergunta mal formulada.